# Conditional object creation

Tags: c#, json

Ok, clearly I am lost in .NET, as it is not what I usually code in. I am trying to create an array of objects during the parsing of a config file, so they can be processed as quickly and efficiently as possible during frame processing. I have been scouring the internet for what I should be doing, but either I don't know the right nomenclature to be search against, or I am going down the wrong path.

Here is the code which is trying to loop through a JSON file and assign pre-made classes along with the config values into an array of objects, in hopes to cycle through those objects at around 60 frames per second.

```
public class UserConfig {

    public object[] myActions = {
    };

    public void processConfig() {

        this.myActions.Clear();

        string json = File.ReadAllText("config.json");
        JToken jsonNodes = JToken.Parse( json );

        WalkNode( jsonNodes, item => {

            object newAction = new object{};

            switch( item["bodyAction"].ToString() ) {
                case "handLeftForward":
                    newAction.detector = new DetectArmForward( JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.HandLeft );
                break;
            }

            switch( item["detectType"].ToString() ) {
                case "distanceMin":
                    switch( newAction.detector.direction ) {
                        case "negative":
                            switch( newAction.detector.path ) {
                                case "Z":
                                    newAction.detector.checker = new CheckNegativeDistanceMinZ( newAction.detector.jointBase, newAction.detector.jointEnd, item.distanceMin );
                                break;
                            }
                        break;
                        case "positive":
                            switch( newAction.detector.path ) {
                                case "Z":
                                    newAction.detector.checker = new CheckPositiveDistanceMinZ( newAction.detector.jointBase, newAction.detector.jointEnd, item.distanceMin );
                                break;
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                break;
            }

            switch( item["executeAction"].ToString() ) {
                case "keyTap":
                    newAction.executer = new executeKeyTap( 123 );
                break;
            }

            this.myActions[ this.myActions.Count() ] = newAction;

        });

    }
}
```

then hopefully I could do something like..

```
    for( action in this.myActions ) {
        if( action.detector.checker.check( joints ) ) {
            action.executer.execute( joints );
        }
    }
```

to check and conditionally execute the methods built from the config processing.

It won't let me use this setup ( and all I've tried ), because the objects must be pre-declared, but I don't know what specific object I'm going to need... so I'm lost :)
Thanks for looking everyone!

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to dynamically generate code on the fly, you might want to look at one of the dynamic languages running on the DLR, like ironpython, it may be better suited to this task. Dynamically assembling object, or what I understand as metaprogramming is more straight forward with python or ruby.

Comment: So, extend C# to use IronPython through DLR? That seems like it would work, but I'd like to do things the true right way, whatever that way is? It can't be unique to need an array of different methods generated on the fly. I don't feel like I'm breaking new ground here, just unsure of the right C# way of doing things. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't just creating data objects and passing them through a function pipeline? You wouldn't be executing a method attached to the object, you would be reacting to the contents of the object. It would change things a little in that the method would execute when the evaluation happens the first time but would negate the need for the foreach later.

Comment: Well the data that the "checker.check()" method compares against will be different on each cycle, that's the purpose of the foreach later. So I can essentially compile a list of all the proper classes, then run directly through them during frame processing.

Comment: If you were to use IronPython, you would write a library in Python that does the object manipulation and then use it in your namespace. Have a static method that takes an object and a method and returns the object with the method attached. You might also look at Roslyn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx, code generation is one of the big use cases being talked about around that project.

Comment: it still seems so strange that I can't just add objects into a generic container and then put that container into an array... There must be an easier way to do this :)

Comment: If all you want to do is dump an object into a container and then get an array out at the other end, you would define a list: var myList = new List<dynamic>(); myList.Add(someObject); var myArray = myList.ToArray(); That will give you an array of dynamic objects but you can change it to whatever object type you want when defining the list. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762916%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: thanks! It looks like that will get the objects into the array properly. But it seems that I am still coming up short on assigning classes to the individual items. Like the `newAction.detector = new DetectArmForward( JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.HandLeft );` line gives me the error of "object does not contain definition for detector...". Am I doing that part wrong?

Comment: The object needs to have a public property called detector, so it needs to come from a class like this: class myObject { public dynamic detector; public dynamic someOtherProperty; }. The object created by the "new DetectArmForward" will be assigned to that property.

Comment: thanks sean_m, I went that route, making the object with as much pre-calculated data as I could, other than setting methods :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is dump an object into a container and then get an array out at the other end, you would define a list:

```
var myList = new List<dynamic>();
myList.Add(someObject);
var myArray = myList.ToArray();
```

That will give you an array of dynamic objects but you can change it to whatever object type you want when defining the list. More info: [.Net Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762916%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The object needs to have a public property called detector, so it needs to come from a class like this:

```
class myObject {
    public dynamic detector; 
    public dynamic someOtherProperty;
}
```

The object created by the `new DetectArmForward` will be assigned to that property.

Comment: thanks! I went this route. The app is a lot more complicated than I posted on here, but this shows me the true mentality I have to get used to with a type restrictive language :)

Answer (score 0):

I might be overlooking something but it seems that you are looking for the command `foreach` instead of for. This should work fine in your case.

```
foreach(object action in this.myActions)
{
    if( action.detector.checker.check( joints ) ) {
        action.executer.execute( joints );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks :) But the main problem is not being able to create those elements I'd want to cycle through